# Migrate/Copy database from one user to another

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. Is it possible to migrate or copy selected databases under one user account to a new user account I created? All accounts are on the same server. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, what kind of user accounts, MySQL users, or server users? MySQL stores its data in one central place, but makes it accessible to users via `GRANT`s.

Comment: All users are MySQL users. I thought I need to move/copy the databases from one user to another. Sorry for my stupid question. I was about to delete the question. Since there might be people who are new to MySQL have similar question, I may just leave it as a reference.

Comment: you can create multiple users for same database with different privileges. if you want to do that.

Comment: @Rock Not a stupid question.  Have a look at [the `GRANT` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) and come back with any specific questions you may have.

Comment: @Rock For example to give `otheruser` access to `yourdbname`: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdbname.* to otheruser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'otheruserpassword'`

Comment: @Michael `IDENTIFIED BY` is only needed if account has not been created before! Also, I think it is not a good idea to create different users with the same password - insecure, at least.

Comment: @Timur Who said anything about 2 users with the same password?

Comment: @Michael I understanded `otheruserpassword` as "password of the first user", because @Rock has only two. If you mean "some other password", sorry, misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about user accounts in a shared server configuration, you could use the `mysqldump` command to create a dump in the old user account, them move the dump to the new user account and import the dump using `mysql < yourdumpfile.sql`.

You will need to provide extra options for creating and then loading the dump, but this is the general idea.

Also, you may want to take a look at [Navicat](http://navicat.com) which lets you drag and drop tables from one database to another even on a different server.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your new user (at the new host) the rights for all the databases via the `GRANT` statement.

Keep in mind that you will have to update the database credentials within your application, when you have a new username and password!